# Iterate through listbox not returning correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a listbox of checkboxes that I want to iterate through and check them all, and uncheck them all. I will also need to find the ones that are checked later. Here is my code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextLabel}" Text="Building Houses Organization:"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="All" Margin="136,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF001BFF" FontSize="11" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding ElementName=BuildingsOrganizationList}" MouseLeftButtonDown="CheckAll"/>
        <TextBlock Text=" | " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Text="None" Foreground="#FF001BFF" FontSize="11" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding ElementName=BuildingsOrganizationList}" MouseLeftButtonDown="CheckNone"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="BuildingsOrganizationList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=BuildingOrganizationGrid, Mode=OneWay}" Height="141">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

You can see that my textblocks have a tag binding to my listbox which contains my checkboxes. Now in the code behind I have the following:

```
private void CheckAll(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock textblock = sender as TextBlock;
    ListBox list = textblock.Tag as ListBox;
    foreach (ListBoxItem item in list.Items)
    {
        //.....
    }
}
```

The problem is that the items are strings. They are not ListBoxItem or CheckBox objects. Why is that?

**EDIT**

I have now added this class

```
class ListItem
{
    private string _name;
    private bool? _isChecked;

    public ListItem()
    {
        _name = "";
        _isChecked = null;
    }

    public ListItem(string name, bool? isChecked)
    {
        Name = name;
        IsChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { _isChecked = value; }
    }
}
```

and have the following lines to populate my list

```
BuildingsOrganizationList.Items.Add(new ListItem(org, true));
```

And the XAML:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="BuildingsOrganizationList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=BuildingOrganizationGrid, Mode=OneWay}" Height="141">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However, my checkboxes are not checked and do not have text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it is because you used `BuildingsOrganizationList.Items.Add(someString)` to populate your ListBox with Items.

`ListBox.Items` will return the Data Objects that are bound to your ListBox, not the UI objects. So if your data objects are strings, then `ListBox.Items` will return you a collection of strings. If you would like to get the UI object that relates to the data object, you need to use the ListBox's [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator_methods.aspx) and call `.ContainerFromItem(dataItem)`

You would be better off filling your ListBox with objects that have an `IsChecked` property and binding the `IsChecked` value of the `CheckBox`. This is because by default WPF will use Virtualized ListBoxes which recycles the UI controls as you scroll, which means the CheckBoxes will lose their `IsChecked` values unless they're bound to something.

For example,

```
BuildingsOrganizationList.Items.Add(new SomeItem { Name="A", IsChecked=false });
BuildingsOrganizationList.Items.Add(new SomeItem { Name="B", IsChecked=false });
BuildingsOrganizationList.Items.Add(new SomeItem { Name="C", IsChecked=false });
```

ListBox's DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

And then you could use

```
private void CheckAll(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (SomeItem item in BuildingsOrganizationList.Items)
    {
        item.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well something similar. I have an observable collection of strings and I set that as the itemsource. What would be the better way of doing it?

Comment: @Justin A better way would be to use an `ObservableCollection<SomeItem>` where `SomeItem` contains properties for `IsChecked` and `Content`

Comment: Strangely, my checkboxes now have no text beside them with it now setup how you discribed.

Comment: @Justin Does the object you are binding to have property name that matches the `Content` binding in your `CheckBox`?

Comment: @Justin The code you posted works fine for me, although I would recommend making `ListItem` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that when you change the value of `IsChecked`, it automatically tells the UI to update

Comment: I ended up adding all the ListItems to an observable collection and then setting that as the itemsource for my listbox. Then, my checkboxes were reflecting the check status and were showing the text. I am not sure why I had to add it to an observable collection first, and then set that to the itemsource. I thought adding it directly to the listbox items collection would have worked. Think it matters that I am using silverlight and not WPF?

Comment: @Justin I have no idea, but it might matter. An `ObservableCollection` will automatically tell WPF to update it's UI when an item gets added to the collection, so I suspect that whatever you were using before wasn't telling the UI to update. Glad you got it worked out though, and I would always recommend using an `ObservableCollection` instead of adding items directly to the ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

How would we know? You added the items, and you bind them to the `Content` of the `CheckBoxes`, that does *not* mean that your items turn into those `CheckBoxes`.

If you want to access the `CheckBox` of the template though you can get it by various nasty means, of which i would *not* recommend any.

Change the item type to some class with a `bool` property that [can be bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) to `CheckBox.IsChecked`. Much cleaner, much easier to handle. In general you should not need any references to actual controls in your code most of the time, try to bind the necessary properties. *(No need for a reference to the ListBox either: Bind the `ListBox.ItemsSource`, iterate over that, change the items' properties)*